# Unmarshal Json Array of object obtained from postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a table in Postgres that is a Jsonb

```
Create Table Business(
    id serial not null primary key,
    id_category integer not null,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    owner varchar(200) not null,
    coordinates jsonb not null,
    reason varchar(300) not null,
    foreign key(id_category) references Category(id)
);
```

as you can see i **store** the **coordinates** as a **jsonb**

ex:

```sql
Insert into Business(id_category, name, owner, coordinates, reason) 
values 
(1,'MyName','Owner', [{"latitude": 12.1268142, "longitude": -86.2754}]','Description')
```

the way that I extract the data and assign it is like this.

```
type Business struct {
    ID int `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Owner string `json:"owner,omitempty"`
    Category string `json:"category,omitempty"`
    Departments []string `json:"departments,omitempty"`
    Location []Coordinates `json:"location,omitempty"`
    Reason string `json:"reason,omitempty"`
}

type Coordinates struct {
    Latitude float64 `json:"latitude,omitempty"`
    Longitude float64 `json:"longitude,omitempty"`
}

func (a Coordinates) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(a)
}

func (a *Coordinates) Scan(value []interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("type assertion to []byte failed")
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(b, &a)
}
```

However, I keep receiving this message.

> sql: Scan error on column index 3, name "coordinates": unsupported
>   Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *models.Coordinates

And the controller that I use to extract the information is this.

```
func (b *BusinessRepoImpl) Select() ([]models.Business, error) {
    business_list := make([]models.Business, 0)
    rows, err := b.Db.Query("SELECT business.id, business.name, business.owner, business.coordinates, business.reason_froggy, category.category FROM business INNER JOIN category on category.id = business.id_category group by business.id, business.name, business.owner, business.coordinates, business.reason_froggy, category.category")
    if err != nil {
        return business_list, err
    }
    for rows.Next() {
        business := models.Business{}
        err := rows.Scan(&business.ID, &business.Name, &business.Owner, &business.Location, &business.Reason, &business.Category)
        if err !=  nil {
            break
        }
        business_list = append(business_list, business)
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        return business_list, err
    }
    return business_list, nil
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this issue? Retrieve the json array of objects and assign it to the coordinates field inside Business.

Comment: That's all the code that i use, or you need something more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this solution is really unoptimized, but it was the only way that it works.

basically i have to obtain the json and then do an unmarshal into the Location attribute.

```
var location string = ""

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(location), &business.Location); err != nil { panic(err) }
```

Answer (score 4):

**1.**

As you can see from the documentation the [`Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) interface, to be satisfied, requires the method

```
Scan(src interface{}) error
```

But your `*Coordinates` type implements a different method

```
Scan(value []interface{}) error
```

The types `interface{}` and `[]interface{}` are two very different things.

**2.**

The Scanner interface must be implemented on the type of the field which you want to pass as an argument to [`rows.Scan`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Scan). That is, you've implemented your `Scan` method on `*Coordinates` but the type of the Location field is `[]Coordinates`.

Again, same thing, the types `*Coordinates` and `[]Coordinates` are two very different things.

---

So the solution is to implement the interface properly and on the proper type.

Note that since Go doesn't allow adding methods to unnamed types, and `[]Coordinates` *is* an unnamed type, you need to declare a new type that you'll then use in place of `[]Coordinates`.

```
type CoordinatesSlice []Coordinates

func (s *CoordinatesSlice) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    switch v := src.(type) {
    case []byte:
        return json.Unmarshal(v, s)
    case string:
        return json.Unmarshal([]byte(v), s)
    }
    return errors.New("type assertion failed")
}

// ...

type Business struct {
    // ...
    Location CoordinatesSlice `json:"location,omitempty"`
    // ...
}
```

---

**NOTE**

If the business location will always have only *one* pair of coordinates store into the db as a jsonb object and change the `Location` type from `CoordinatesSlice` to `Coordinates` and accordingly move the `Scanner` implementation from `*CoordinatesSlice` to `*Coordinates`.